# TypeError when loading HERE js 3.1 map with CanvasLayer

Tags: here-api

I have simple html/js website project with HERE map in it (using the new v3.1 API). After the website loads it promptly crashes with obscure TypeError that says "cannot read property 'fc' of undefined".

Tried including other HERE modules like mapsjs-data.js, mapsjs-core-legacy.js etc. Tried every possible way to initialize map and canvas layer, tried other browsers, nothing even affected the problem.

[image: exception]

It only crashes when I add some CanvasLayer (which I need to draw some stuff on the map) otherwise everything works ok and map displays fine:

```
map.addLayer(new H.map.layer.CanvasLayer(function (ctx, renderParams) { return H.map.render.RenderState.DONE; }));
```

The draw handler does not even get invoked once (hence it's not it's contents). It just crashes.
The initialization of the map is straightforward and follows official examples:

```
const defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
const baseTiles = defaultLayers.vector.normal.map;
const map = new H.Map(
    $("#mapContainer")[0],
    baseTiles,
    {
       zoom: 10,
       center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
    });
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
Complete example to reproduce the error based on the official quick start tutorial

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
    <script>
        // Initialize the platform object:
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            'apikey': '{YOUR_APIKEY}'
        });

        // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
        var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

        // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
        var map = new H.Map(
            document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
            maptypes.vector.normal.map,
            {
                zoom: 10,
                center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
            });

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        //this line causes the website to crash upon load
        map.addLayer(new H.map.layer.CanvasLayer(function (ctx, renderParams) { return H.map.render.RenderState.DONE; }));
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you initialize  `platform` ? You need to provide `apikey` in version 3.1 while it was `app_id` and `app_code` in version 3.0

Comment: @StephaneL yes I updated that, platform initialization is straightforward like in the examples: `const platform = new H.service.Platform({apikey: "xxx",useCIT: false,useHTTPS: true});`

Comment: Can you please post more code snippets, we are not able to reproduce your error.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I edited the post to include a complete code, just run it. It fails for me 100% of the time. Development machine is windows 10 x64 (newest 1903 update), browser is latest chrome. IDE is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @Nemo, thank you, we have been able to reproduce the error and we will get back to you with the fix as soon as possible.

Comment: This issue has now been worked upon and fixed.

Comment: it's been "fixed" in favor of a slightly different error. Now it says "Cannot read property 'Db' of undefined" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Nemo, please check as the error is confirmed to be fixed.

Comment: It works now although there are numerous issues with rendering and coordinate calculation that used to work fine before but I'm guessing we just need to revise the rendering code to adjust it to the new version, thanks!